What kind of object is a function in the context of gauge theory?
In the context of differential geometry, we have the Levi-Civita connection that tells us how to take derivatives of tensors. Two examples of the covariant derivative are
$$\nabla_\mu \phi = \partial_\mu \phi, \quad (\nabla_\mu X)^\nu = \partial_\mu X^\nu + \Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\nu X^\lambda.$$
In other words, the covariant derivative of a scalar (or (0,0) tensor) is just the usual partial derivative, where as for a vector (or a (0,1) tensor) one needs to add extra terms so that the derivative is left covariant.
However, when studying gauge theory (of which I am definitely not an expert), when considering the simple U(1) symmetry group one gets that to calculate for example the derivative of a function $\phi$ one has to consider the connection given by the gauge potential and its associated gauge covariant derivative i.e. $$ D_\mu \phi = \partial_\mu \phi + A_\mu \phi.$$
Does this lead to some kind of interpretation in which $\phi$ is not a scalar function but rather in some sense a (0,1) tensor?

The terminology used in physics texts is often a bit imprecise, and thus the word "scalar" is somewhat ambiguous. Often if a function $\phi(x)$ of the coordinates is a "scalar", it means that during a coordinate transformation $\bar x=\bar x(x)$, it transforms as $\bar\phi(\bar x)=\phi(x(\bar x))$, i.e. the value of the function at each geometric point does not change, but the functional form of the function itself does change due to the transformation of variables. This "definition" is compatible also with multi-component objects $\phi^a(x)$ that have the property that under a change of coordinates, each component transforms the way specified above.
Other times, a "scalar" is equivalent to a "real-valued function".

What happens in gauge theory is that $\phi$ is a section of some vector bundle, i.e. there is a vector bundle $(E,\pi,M)$ over spacetime $M$ and $\phi:M\rightarrow E$ is such that $\pi\circ\phi=\mathrm{id}_M$. This is quite an abstract object, definitely not a "scalar" in the intuitive sense.
But, if you introduce a local frame $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ in the vector bundle, then in the domain of this frame you can write $\phi=\phi^ae_a$, and the coefficients $\phi^a$ are now real-valued functions, which under coordinate transformations in the base space $M$, behave as "scalars". However under changes $\bar{e}_b = U^a_{\ b}e_a$ of the frame in the vector bundle (essentially, gauge transformations), these coefficients transform nontrivially as $ \bar{\phi}^a=\bar{U}^a_{\ b}\phi^b $ (where $\bar U$ is the inverse of $U$).
Since in general $U$ is position-dependent, this is why the covariant derivative is needed, since the ordinary partial derivatives of these components would not transform in such a nice way under a gauge transformation, due to derivatives of $U$ appearing.

What might be confusing about the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ case is that $\phi$ appears as an ordinary (but complex-valued!) function $\phi$, i.e. it has only a single component. But it still transforms nontrivially under gauge transformations, so the covariant derivative is still needed. And of course, it has one complex component, but it means it has two real components. You can think of $\phi$ abstractly as a section of a complex line bundle that has an $\mathrm{U}(1)$ structure group.
It is also a common way to say that $\phi$ is a spacetime scalar, but an internal $\mathrm{U}(1)$ vector, and this latter property is what necessitates the nontrivial covariant derivative.
